# Javascript button doesn't work when in form tag

Tags: javascript, php, forms

When I put form tags in my php file, my javascript function addmore(index) stopped working. I can't figure why? Without the form tags it works, but then I don't have my submit button.

**IN MY HTML THERE ARE SEVERAL TEXTAREAS WHERE I INSERT QUESTIONS FOR USERS**

```
<textarea name"que[1]"></textarea>
<textarea name"que[2]"></textarea>
<textarea name"que[3]"></textarea>
```

**MY PHP FILE SHOULD PRESENT QUESTIONS WITH ANSWER FIELDS - THEN USER SUBMIT IT**

```
<?php
<form action="result.php" method="post">
$content = "";
$question = $_POST['que'];
$length = count($_POST['que']);

for($j=1; $j<$length+1; $j++) {

if($_POST['pitanje'][$j] != "") {
$area = '<textarea name="ans'.$j.'1"></textarea>';
$addmore = '<button type="button" name="addmore" onClick="addmore('.$j.');">Add more</button>';
$content .= $j.') '.$question[$j].'<br/>'.$area.'<br/><div id="inner'.$j.'"></div>'.$addmore.'<br/><br/>';}}

echo $content;
echo'<br/><input type="submit" value="CALCULATE"></form>';
?>
```

**MY JAVASCRIPT FILE IS FOR FUNCTION WHICH ADDS MORE ANSWER FIELDS**

```
var am = [];
for(var i=1; i<101; i++){
am[i] = 1;}

function addmore(index) {
        am[index]++;
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "ans" + index + am[index];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("inner"+index).appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Is clicking the button causing a postback?

Comment: "stopped working" is not a very accurate description of the problem

Comment: Yes. The post method leads them to another page (.php) which gathers results. But the problem is the javascript button and addmore function

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the buttons are triggering the form submit. try this:

```
onClick="return addmore('.$j.');">
.....
function addmore(index) {
....
return false;
}
```

Comment: The buttons is defined with `type="button"`, so it's not a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the error is because the form tag is not being echoed or assigned to a variable.

Comment: I missed to echo a form tag. But, this isn't a solution, it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Options...

- Change the `button name`
- Change the name of the `function`
- Remove the attribute `name` in the `button`
- Use `<input type="button" />` instead of `<button></button>`
- ...

... any should do.

like

```
<button name="buttonName" onclick="functionName()">addnew in html?</button>
<button name="buttonName" onclick="otherFunctionName()">addnew</button>
<button onclick="functionName()">addnew</button>
```

or just

```
<input type="button" value="addnew" onclick="functionName()" />
```

See a **[simplifyed JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z5y9/)**

Answer (score -1):

I guess that austin is right, I tried with the button outside of the form and then it works.

If you move the Button out from your form tags like this it will work, you have an "addmore" button right on top and get as many textareas as you like below (one html page to illustrate in e jsfiddle or simmilar):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var am = [];
    for(var i=1; i<101; i++){
    am[i] = 1;}

    function addmore(index) {
            am[index]++;
            var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
            textarea.name = "ans" + index + am[index];
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
            document.getElementById("inner"+index).appendChild(div);
    }
    </script>
<body><button type="button" name="addmore" onClick="addmore(1);">Add more</button>
<form action="result.php" method="post">1) $_POST["que"]<br/><textarea name="ans11"></textarea><br/><div id="inner1"></div><br/><br/><br/><input type="submit" value="CALCULATE"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also found this solution, that might solve it properly. you need to

1. may as first change the button to input type=button,...
2. must not name the button or input the same as your function.

This highlights both solutions:

```
<?php
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var am = [];
for(var i=1; i<101; i++){
am[i] = 1;}

function addmore(index) {
    am[index]++;
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "ans" + index + am[index];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inner"+index).appendChild(div);
}
</script>
<body>';
    $content = "";
    $question = 'question:';
    $length = 99;
    $j =1;
    $addmore = '<button type="button" name="addsmore" onClick="addmore('.$j.');">Add more</button>';
    echo $addmore;
    echo '<form action="result.php" method="post">';

    $area = '<input type="button" value="Add 2more" name="addsdmore" onClick="addmore('.$j.');"></input>
            <textarea name="ans'.$j.'1"></textarea>';
    $content .= $j.') '.$question.'<br/>'.$area.'<br/>
            <div id="inner'.$j.'"></div><br/><br/>';

    echo $content;
    echo'<br/><input type="submit" value="CALCULATE"></form>';
    echo '</body>
</html>';
?>
```

Comment: The javascript works when there are no form tags (these two lines of code). Try it, the code is complete. But when I add the form and the form button, you can't add textareas anymore.

Comment: The console said: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: What is the problem here, I cannot see the solution... Everything seems fine, but when there is a form, it breaks...

Comment: In what way you make it work. Can u paste the code. Because when I apply Austin's solutuion, it doesn't work for me